# SFTP Support for curl on OSX

Tags: macos, curl, ssh, sftp, homebrew

I am trying to get SFTP support for curl in OSX. I installed curl via

```
$ brew install curl --with-ssh
```

and I also symlinked the homebrew version to the /usr/bin via

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/curl /usr/bin/curl
```

But I am still getting a

```
curl: (1) Protocol sftp not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

when using

```
$ curl sftp://some.host.com/path/to/file
```

My endeavor is connected to an issue for the awesome git-ftp https://github.com/resmo/git-ftp/issues/146

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just a short note: Seems nowadays you need to:


    brew install curl --with-libssh2

Comment: @DerWOK You'r the real MVP here, this is better than the answer.

Comment: As of August 2018 brew install curl --with-ssh automatically translated it to --with-libssh2.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

run 'curl -V' and see if SFTP is listed as a supported protocol.

If it isn't, curl needs to be rebuilt with libssh2 to get the support built-in.

Comment: Hi and thanks. There was indeed no sftp listed, although I installed curl with ssh. Turned out that homebrew installed curl into `/usr/local/Cellar/curl/7.28.0/bin/curl` so a redo of the symlink did it for me: `ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/curl/7.28.0/bin/curl /usr/bin/curl`

Comment: Got here because of the same error, also using git-ftp. Small world... FYI, Homebrew says, after building curl: This formula is keg-only, so it was not symlinked into /usr/local. Mac OS X already provides this software and installing another version in parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.

Answer (score 2):

Since the `--with-libssh2` option was [removed from brew](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/37255), this is the way to go:

```
brew install curl-openssl
```

Be aware:

```
curl is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because macOS already provides this software and installing another version in
parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.

If you need to have curl first in your PATH, run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/curl/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

or call it directly by using:

```
/usr/local/opt/curl/bin/curl ...
```

Answer (score 1):

For now, you can install just 'curl' `Formerly known as: curl-openssl` with the following command:

```
brew install curl
```

and then the command for example:

```
/opt/homebrew/opt/curl/bin/curl -u user:password sftp://sftp.host.com/Export/file.txt
```

Source https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/curl