# Accessing SFTP via Curl in Rstudio

Tags: r, macos, rcurl

I am trying to use the RCurl library to access an SFTP site to download files on a MacOS running Monterrey v12.4.  As has happened to others, when RCurl calls the curl libraries SFTP is not enabled.

Following [SFTP Support for curl on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13171550/sftp-support-for-curl-on-osx) I installed curl with openssl using homebrew.  I uninstalled the curl and Rcurl libraries in RStudio.

In a terminal window, running 'curl -v' shows that sftp is available.
In RStudio, running "system('which curl')" shows sftp is available.

However, when I try to retrieve a file via SFTP using the RCurl library, I receive the message:

```
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE) : 
Protocol "sftp" not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

I thought maybe the PATH was not set correctly.  I added the following line to my .Renviron file.

PATH=/opt/homebrew/opt/curl/bin:$PATH

At this stage, it's not clear to me why sftp is not supported when trying to access a file on an SFTP site when using the RCurl library.

What else can I do to try to diagnose why this is occurring?

Comment: Did you install the RCurl package from source? Or did you install the precompile binaries. Maybe if you try `install.packages("RCurl", type="source")` that will use your system curl. I think that's set at compile time.

Comment: `curl::curl_version()` will show your the support of R libcurl. Compare that with  curl -V. `curl:::R_curl_version` will show the library

Comment: @RicVillalba.   The curl::curl_version output is different than 'curl -V'
The former shows curl v7.79.1 and no SFTP support.  The latter shows curl v7.86.0 w/ SFTP support.   

My intention was that modifying the PATH in .Renviron fixed this problem.  But it apparently did not.

Comment: @MrFlick, I've tried to install from source.  It exits w/ an error stating the install script cannot find sed and expr.    I'll have to fix that problem first.

Comment: @MrFlick the install problem has been fixed.  The libraries curl and Rcurl have been installed from source.   Unfortunately, this does not solve the problem.   R is still using the older version of the curl library which does not have SFTP support.

Comment: I confirmed my PATH.  The first entry in $PATH is /opt/homebrew/opt/curl/bin which is where the v7.86.0 with SFTP support executable is.    As far as I'm concerned, R should be finding this.

But, the output of curl::curl_version() still shows the older version.

Comment: I've now installed the latest version of R (4.2.2), RStudio (2022.07.2 Build 576), uninstalled curl and RCurl, and reinstalled from source, but the problem remains unsolved.

The results of curl::curl_version() shows curl version 7.82.0
A "system('curl -V') shows curl version 7.82.0
A "curl -V" run in a terminal window shows curl version 7.86.0 with SFTP support. 

My PATH env variable currently includes the directory that V7.86.0 of curl is in.
Any guidance on next steps is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.  In the post
[SFTP Support for curl on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13171550/sftp-support-for-curl-on-osx)

there is code to enable SFTP support in curl on MacOS.

I ran the three lines:

```
PATH <- Sys.getenv("PATH")
version <- '7.86.0'
Sys.setenv(PATH = paste0("/opt/homebrew/Cellar/curl/", version, "/bin:", PATH))
```

and SFTP is enabled in RCurl.

an "echo $PATH" run from the terminal shows "/opt/homebrew/opt/curl/bin" in the path.  I assumed this meant the OpenSSL enabled curl was being used, but that is not the case.   Apparently the R PATH is different than the MacOS PATH.

My next step is to add this line to my .Rprofile file so that it is included each time I start R.